# Android - How to preserve socket connection when a service is restarted

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, connection

I have a service which creates a socket server and a client connects to it. The connection is kept open to transfer data. The service is `START_STICKY`. So when user kills the app by swiping it from recent tasks, the `onCreate` and `onStartCommand` functions are called again. I don't want to re-initialize the socket and instead preserve it's state as it was before the user swiped the task to kill it and keep transferring the data uninterrupted.

```
public class SendTasksService extends Service {
    static Socket socket=null;
    static boolean shouldRun=true;
    static final int port = PORT_NO;
    static ServerSocket listener = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("Service onBind.");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        System.out.println("Service onCreate.");
        shouldRun=true;
        try {
            if(socket==null){
                System.out.println("Starting Listening..");
                listener = new ServerSocket(port);
                System.out.println("Notification Started.");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Continuing With Old Socket..");
                /*
                    How to get the socket if the connection
                    was made before swipe killing the app from recent
                */
            }
        }catch(Exception ioe){
            System.out.println("Exception in listening.");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        System.out.println("Service onDestroy.");
        closeConnection();
    }

    public void closeConnection(){
        //Wind up work and close connection
        /*
            This should also remove any socket information saved anywhere
        */
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {
        System.out.println("Service onStartCommand.");
        try{
            new AsyncAction().execute();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private class AsyncAction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            while(shouldRun) {
                try {
                    if(socket==null) {
                        socket = listener.accept();
                        /*
                            Socket connection established here.
                            Save this socket state or preserve it somehow
                            So that connection does not break on killing the app
                        */
                    }else{
                        /*
                            Continue with the old socket data, and resume connection
                        */
                    }
                    if(socket==null)
                        continue;
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Exception after Break");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }
    }
}
```

What I have tried?

1. Try to save socket as using `gson` in `SharedPreferences`.
   Couldn't retrieve the socket object back.

   ```
   SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().
                        getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
   editor.putBoolean("onGoingConnection",false);
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   String json = gson.toJson(socket);
   editor.putString("ExistingSocket",json);
   editor.apply()
   ```
2. Create a `static` saving Socket in the activity which started the service. It was always null on service resume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more tinkering, and couldn't get around to save the connection. So I figured if I could notify my client that my server wants it to reconnect before the connection goes down, I can reconnect automatically. If anyone finds this useful.
Just added `android:stopWithTask="false"` in the service tag of manifest and over rid `onTaskRemoved` in the service. In `onTaskRemoved`, I sent the signal to client to reconnect to the server.

```
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    System.out.println("Service onTaskRemoved.");
    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.print("RECONNECT\0");
        out.flush();
        out = null;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in closing connection.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to re-initialize the socket and instead preserve it's state as it was before the user swiped the task to kill it and keep transferring the data uninterrupted.

By definition, that is not possible. Your process was terminated. Your socket goes away when your process does.

> Try to save socket as using gson in SharedPreferences.

A socket cannot be persisted. You saved the `toString()` of the `Socket`, nothing more.

Comment: So I cannot save my connection from being destroyed? Another solution could be using datagram, but that would involve changing my client too.

Comment: @dumplingParadox: "So I cannot save my connection from being destroyed?" -- correct. You cannot assume that your process will be around forever, even with a service. Once your process is terminated, it may be some time before the system restarts it, even with `START_STICKY`. You need to design your app to support arbitrary amounts of time where you have no process and no connection to the server.

Comment: I figured a way around it, you were right about not being able to save the state. Marked as correct answer. :))

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by making a class extends application

```
public class Engine extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    /* do something here */

}
}
```

And then in the manifest do something like

```
<manifest...>

<application
    android:name=".[yourclassname]" //
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: A custom `Application` class does not stop the process from being terminated.

Comment: but the question is to retain the state of the socket ?